# keep local or session storage between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, local-storage

A newbie Question here, I have searched on stackOverflow and nothing has answered my question...

I have a home site lets say homesite.com there I have a login and if everything went smoothly I redirect the user to app.homesite.com there I look at the session or localstorage to see if it is a valid user

my question is how can I have the session or localstorage always saved? because when my page changes to another url the memory is gone... I am testing the pages locally localhost8808 and localhost9000 I don't know if this has something to do with that

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064233/using-session-storage-across-subdomains

Comment: The following link is fairly old, so I'm not sure on if the spec for local storage has changed, but 3-4 years ago this was the work around for domain/subdomain and local storage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7722326/1992129

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use localStorage across subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains)

Comment: @ArthurWeborg - I second this link. You're running into a restriction with accessing Local Storage *across domains*. Local storage will work between pages, but not natively across domains, subdomains (www, app, etc), or ports

Answer (score 0):

**LocalStorage** saves data permanently until deleted by developer or user . Session storage is only available in current window . If you are already using local storage and your data is clearing when url changes you will probably need to configure your domain to :

**Example :**

**app.homesite.com/home**

**app.homesite.com/login**

**app.homesite.com/profile**

ect...